# How many different passwords of length 4 can be made with atleast 1 digit in it.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Consider the character set of total 62 characters : - 26 capital letters 26 small letters 10 digits

I know that i can solve this by

Total passwords   -  Total passwords only containing characters

That is $62^4 - 52^4$.

But i want to know why this following direct approach is not correct?

$(10 x 52 x 52 x 52)  +  (10 x 10 x 52 x 52) + (10 x 10 x 10 x 52) + 10 x 10 x 10 x 10)$

Consider the case of exactly 1 digit. (10 x 52 x 52 x 52)
Should we not only consider to multiply the total number of digits at single place to the product of total number of characters at 3 other places. Multiplication is associative so placing 10 at any position should not change the result like

$(10 x 52 x 52 x 52) = (52 x 10 x 52 x 52) = (52 x 52 x 10 x 52) = (52 x 52 x 52 x 10)$

please explain in detail different ways of approaching this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the case where there is only one digit, you must consider the 4 places where the digit can be so you should multiply $10\cdot {52}^3$ by ${4 \choose 1}$ to account for the four different placements of the digit.  Applying this to the other three cases yields:

$$\left(10 \cdot {52}^3 \cdot {4 \choose 1}\right) + \left(10^2 \cdot {52}^2 \cdot {4 \choose 2}\right) + \left({10}^3 \cdot 52 \cdot {4 \choose 3}\right) + \left({10}^4 \cdot {4 \choose 4}\right)=7464720={62}^4-{52}^4$$

Comment: If you're not familiar with combinatorics conceptually you should try watching some youtube videos or do a google search.